# Regex troubleshooting, unable to ignore specific character using atomic classes

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

In my string of only alphabets, I'm trying to find the neighbouring characters of a motif `GYG`, for certain depth `dep`. However, if a character `Y` is found before the desired depth is reached, the regex engine should break and return all the characters found between `GYG` and `Y`.

To illustrate:

- For `dep = 2` in `XXXGYGXXXYXGYGXX`, the desired matches are `XX` `XX` `X` `XX`
- For `dep = 3` in `XXXGYGXXXYXGYGXX`, the desired matches are `XXX` `XXX` `X` `XX`

The expression I used: `(?:GYG|Y)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=GYG)\w{1,dep}(?=Y)|(?<=GYG)\w{1,dep}|(?<=Y)\w{1,dep}(?=GYG)|\w{dep}(?=GYG)` where `dep` is user defined.

Using this toy-example, my regex-expression works fine. However, using my real string (given below), it doesn't. I suspect something's up with the atomic group `(?<=Y)\w{1,dep}(?=GYG)|\w{dep}(?=GYG)`, but i can't seem to figure out where.

My code:

```
import regex as re 
ls = []
regex = '(?:GYG)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=GYG)\w{1,3}(?=Y)|(?<=GYG)\w{1,3}|(?<=Y)\w{1,3}|\w{1,3}?(?=GYG)'
seq = 'MASNDYTQQATQSYGAYPTQPGQGYSQQSSQPYGQQSYSGYSQSTDTSGYGQSSYSSYGQSQNTGYGTQSTPQGYGSTGGYGSSQSSQSSYGQQSSYPGYGQQPAPSSTSGSYGSSSQSSSYGQPQSGSYSQQPSYGGQQQSYGQQQSYNPPQGYGQQNQYNS'
for matchedobj in re.finditer(regex, seq):
    ls.append(matchedobj.group(0))
```

Output:

```
['DTS', 'QSS', 'QNT', 'TQS', 'TPQ', 'STG', 'SSQ', 'SYP', 'QQP', 'PPQ', 'QQN']
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/HAPO2B/2)

Comment: wish i could tell what to match. is rx101 link match correct ?

Comment: The 'expression'' you used not match code expression, yes ?

Comment: there are no atomic groups in expresuns, pseudo atomac yes

Comment: The expression I used matches `SYP`; However, it should break when `Y` is seen.

Comment: Perhaps you can match any word char except the Y `(?:GYG|Y)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=GYG)\w{1,3}|(?<=Y)\w{1,3}(?=GYG)|[^\WY]{3}(?=GYG)`https://regex101.com/r/Y9QGCN/1/

Comment: @wimyang Did that work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for your suggestion! It worked for the specific case `dep <= 3` indeed. 

However, it doesn't always work. Changing `dep = 4` makes the engine capture a `GYG`.. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/Y9QGCN/2) you can see between match 5 and match 6, `YG` is matched instead of `GYG`.. So it seems that the backtracking captures `GYG`, rendering the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` useless..

Comment: @wimyang I don't see GYG as a match https://regex101.com/r/p6aj58/1

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. Let me rephrase. 

Increasing the `dep` from 3 to 4 makes the engine capture part of the `GYG` motif [Here, I only consider this part of the regex which goes wrong]
(https://regex101.com/r/Y9QGCN/3). Between match 3 and match 4, part of the `GYG` is captured, namely the left `G` So it seems that the `[^\WY]{4}` manages to capture part of the `GYG` motif, rendering the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` useless..

Comment: @wimyang Perhaps like this for dep is 4 https://regex101.com/r/vMfHRD/1

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is that the negated pattern `GYG` is symmetric that it contains `G` characters on both sides `Y`. Therefore, positive look-arounds do not work for various reasons.

There are two ways two approach this problem. The first, is by using look-arounds.

**The first method: Look around method**

To setup the look-around about the `GYG` motif but still capture stand-alone `G` characters, we first negate *all* `G` characters. Since `Y` characters also shouldn't be capture, we put both `G` and `Y` in our negated class: `[^YG]`. This sets us up for the look around given by `G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)` and is explained step-by-step below by @The fourth bird. Please take a look at his answer.

The trick is to re-capture `G` characters which were initially skipped by the negated class, using `G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)`. This ensures that `G` characters in `GY` and `YG patterns as well as those standing alone are still captured.

`regex = (?:(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+(?=GYG)|(?<=GYG)(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+)`

Since we would like to capture on both sides of `GYG`, the first alternation is positive look-ahead `(?=GYG)`. Repeat the same steps for the positive look-behind `(?<=GYG)`

Code for the first-method:

```
import regex as re 
ls = []
seq = 'MASNDYTQQATQSYGAYPTQPGQGYSQQSSQPYGQQSYSGYSQSTDTSGYGQSSYSSYGQSQNTGYGTQSTPQGYGSTGGYGSSQSSQSSYGQQSSYPGYGQQPAPSSTSGSYGSSSQSSSYGQPQSGSYSQQPSYGGQQQSYGQQQSYNPPQGYGQQNQYNS'
regex = (?:(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+(?=GYG)|(?<=GYG)(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+)
for matchedobj in re.finditer(regex, seq):
    ls.append(matchedobj.group(0))
```

**The second method: Anchoring at `GYG`**

The second method is suggested to me by another user: Wiktor. Solution [here](https://regex101.com/r/Lb9qXp/2). The regex expression looks for all `GYG` patterns; it then expands using the greedy `?` quantifier.

`regex = ((?:(?!GYG)[^Y]){1,3})?GYG((?:(?!GYG)[^Y]){1,3})?`

The only "downside" with this method is that it requires a bit more book-keeping on the groups.

Code for the second-method:

```
import regex as re 
ls = []
seq = 'MASNDYTQQATQSYGAYPTQPGQGYSQQSSQPYGQQSYSGYSQSTDTSGYGQSSYSSYGQSQNTGYGTQSTPQGYGSTGGYGSSQSSQSSYGQQSSYPGYGQQPAPSSTSGSYGSSSQSSSYGQPQSGSYSQQPSYGGQQQSYGQQQSYNPPQGYGQQNQYNS'
regex = ((?:(?!GYG)[^Y]){1,3})?GYG((?:(?!GYG)[^Y]){1,3})?
for matchedobj in re.finditer(regex, seq):
    ls.append(matchedobj.group(1)) # gives the matches preceeding GYG
    ls.append(matchedobj.group(2)) # gives matches that follow GYG
```

Comment: Note I used the word "anchoring" in a bit different meaning than usual: `GYG` works as an "anchor" here, some literal, obligatory chunk of letters (unlike `\A`, `^`, `\Z` or `$` anchors proper that just match start/end of string positions), but once the `GYG` pattern matches, there is no re-trying the positions between the characters that make up `GYG`. You can say that literal regex parts are atomic by themselves, but that would be another abuse of regex terminology :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *SKIP *FAIL, you might use an alternation with lookarounds.

If you want to match n chars before or after matching GYG, but if you encounter a Y in the range between the GYG and n, return what is matched inbetween, you could use a negated character class matching any word char except YG.

Only match a G when not surrounded by GY on the left or YG on the right.

```
(?:(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+(?=GYG)|(?<=GYG)(?:[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)){1,3}+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UgTiqr/1)

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^\WYG]` Match any word char except Y or G
    - `|` Or
    - `G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)` Do match a G when not preceded by GYG or followed by YG
  - `){1,4}+` Close the group and repeat 1-4 times using a possessive quantifier
  - `(?=GYG)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is GYG
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=GYG)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is GYG
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^\WYG]` Match any word char except Y or G
    - `|` Or
    - `G(?<!GYG)(?!YG)` Do match a G when not preceded by GYG or followed by YG
  - `){1,4}+` Close the group and repeat 1-4 times using a possessive quantifier
- `)` Close group

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Negating G (using `[^YG]`) works because there is the alternation that you capture `G` when it is not to the right of `GY` and to the right of `GY`.. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you could use the negation with an alternation. You don't match what is listed using the negated character class for example `[^YG]` and then you can use the or `|` to create an exception where you want to match either Y or G. In this part `[^\WYG]|G(?<!GYG)` you match any word character except Y or G or you match G when not preceded by GYG

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks a bunch